# Why doesn't file load by URI?

Tags: 8, files

I have a file URI something like private://somefolder/myfile.pdf. Certain users don't have access to the file so I am trying to change that using hook_file_download($uri). In that code I need to load the file and the examples I have seen suggest:

```
  $files = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
    ->getStorage('file')
    ->loadByProperties(['uri' => $uri]);
```

but when I do this, $files is empty.

The file is there, and as an admin I can open the file. Also, if I use this code:

```
  $files = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
    ->getStorage('file')
    ->loadByProperties(['fid' => 12345]);
```

it does load the file.

Also, if I strip off the private://somefolder/ and loadBy filename, it also works.

What am I missing here?

Possible answer and bug in core?
Although the $uri which is passed to hook_file_download($uri) is in the format mentioned above (which does not work); if I try to load by uri using this:

```
private://somefolder\myfile.pdf (note last last slash in Windows format)
```

then it does work.

Answer (score -1):

I ended up with this:

```
  $uri = preg_replace("~\/(?!.*\/)~", DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $uri);
  /* @var \Drupal\file\FileInterface[] $files */
  $files = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
    ->getStorage('file')
    ->loadByProperties(['uri' => $uri]);
```

but pretty sure this is a bug in core.

Comment: If this is a bug in core they need something reproducible. You would have to explain how you get the malformed URI stored in the database.